# cassandra Select on indexed columns and with IN clause for the PRIMARY KEY are not supported

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

In Cassandra, I'm using the cql:

```
select msg from log where id in ('A', 'B') and filter1 = 'filter'
```

(where `id` is the partition key and `filter1` is a secondary index and `filter1` cannot be used as a cluster column)

This gives the response:

```
Select on indexed columns and with IN clause for the PRIMARY KEY are not supported
```

How can I change CQL to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to split that up into separate queries of:

```
select msg from log where id = 'A' and filter1 = 'filter';
```

and

```
select msg from log where id = 'B' and filter1 = 'filter';
```

Due to the way data is partitioned in Cassandra, CQL has a lot of seemingly arbitrary restrictions (to discourage inefficient queries and also because they are complex to implement).

Over time I think these restrictions will slowly be removed, but for now we have to work around them.  For more details on the restrictions, see [A deep look at the CQL where clause](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause).

Answer (score 2):

Another option, is that you could build a table specifically for this query (a query table) with `filter1` as a partition key and `id` as a clustering key.  That way, your query works and you avoid having a secondary index all-together.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TABLE log 
    (filter1 text, 
          id text, 
         msg text, 
     PRIMARY KEY (filter1, id));
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO log (filter1, id, msg) 
                             VALUES ('filter','A','message A');
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO log (filter1, id, msg)
                             VALUES ('filter','B','message B');
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO log (filter1, id, msg) 
                             VALUES ('filter','C','message C');
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT msg FROM log 
                             WHERE filter1='filter' AND id IN ('A','B');

 msg
-----------
 message A
 message B

(2 rows)
```

You would still be using an "IN" which isn't known to perform well either.  But you would also be specifying a partition key, so it might perform better than expected.